# Sitecore Media Framework Brightcove 2.1 and Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore, brightcove

I am trying to install the Sitecore Media Framework Brightcove 2.1 edition with Sitecore 8. All is fine and good up until the point where I install the Brightcove package. Out of the box, the framework is configured to work with Lucene but we are using Solr in our instance. I'm wondering if you have any reference material to move Media Framework for Brightcove from Lucene to Solr. I have seen blog posts online but none of them detail on how to move the specifics of the Lucene config file to Solr.

I'm wondering if there is anything available like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present Sitecore doesn't support Solr with the Brightcove connector. You can successfully run the Brightcove connector on Lucene while everything else is using Solr.